# Evaluate BERT Model param.requires_grad

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have a doubt regarding the evaluation on the test set of my bert model. During the eval part param.requires_grad is suppose to be True or False? indipendently if I did a full fine tuning during training or not. My model is in model.eval() mode but I want to be sure to not force nothing wrong in the Model() class when i call it for evaluation. Thanks !

```
  if freeze_bert == 'True':
        for param in self.bert.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
            #logging.info('freeze_bert: {}'.format(freeze_bert)) 
            #logging.info('param.requires_grad: {}'.format(param.requires_grad))
    if freeze_bert == 'False':
        for param in self.bert.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you freeze your model then the parameter of the corresponding modules must not be updated, *i.e.* they should not require gradient computation: `requires_grad=False`.

Note [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) also has a [`requires_grad_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.requires_grad_) method:

```
if freeze_bert == 'True':
    self.bert.requires_grad_(False)

elif freeze_bert == 'False:
    self.bert.requires_grad_(True)
```

Ideally `freeze_bert` would be a boolean and you would simply do:

```
self.bert.requires_grad_(not freeze_bert)
```

Comment: Thanks but I know this, mine is a theoretical question, When I test the model should the requires_grad set to True or False?

Comment: That's irrelevant since there are no backpropagation or parameter updates during validation and testing. In any case, you should be using [`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) for this kind of inference which ***will*** make `requires_grad=False` anyways.